# BelongsToMany Laravel 5.4 Class 'Departamento::class' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, relacionamento

Tenho varias 4 tabelas Começando com Users -> Departamentos -> categoria_departamento -> categoria -> postagems;
Onde a tabela categoria_departamento ela serve como pivo para relação many to many entre a tabela departamentos e a tabela categoria.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São as 4 últimas tabelas.

Quando entro na model Categoria e tendo fazer um belongsToMany na model Departamento aparece um FatalThrowableError dizendo que minha class foi foi encontrada (Class 'Departamento::class' not found)
Estou fazendo assim, no model Categoria.php:

```
public function departamentos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Departamento::class', 'categoria_departamento');
}
```

E no model Departamentos fiz assim veja:

```
public function categorias()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Categoria::class' , 'categoria_departamento');
}
```

Realmente não sei o por que esta dando esse erro.
O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Tira as aspas aonde tem ::class

Comment: Não vei... Não acredito que eu não imaginei que poderia ser as aspas.. kkkkkk Caracas man. Certinho

Comment: Pq com alguma tem que ter altas e outros não?

Comment: Não entendi Natan a ultima pergunta!

Comment: Corretor automático mudou a palavra. A pergunta é. PQ com alguns relacionamentos precisa de aspas e outras não?

Comment: Mais vc resolver a parada.

Comment: Tudo vai depender de como você utiliza como está descrito na minha resposta ou Departamento::class ou "App\Departamento" que significam a mesma coisa ... ! ;) vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é sem as aspas simples nesse caso onde `Departamento::class` s[ignifica que vai ser obtido o nome totalmente qualificado da classe](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) e vale lembrar que essa comando funciona a partir da versão ***`5.5.x`*** do [php](/questions/tagged/php), ***exemplo***:

```
public function departamentos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Departamento::class, 'categoria_departamento');
}
```

Para exemplificar melhor se sua classe é feita dentro do `namespace` `App` o comando `Departamento::class` retorna: `App\Departamento` (***ou seja***, *o nome da classe e seu namespace correspondent*e), que é o que precisa dentro do `$this->belongsToMany`.

***Referencia:*** [Class name resolution via ::class](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name)